# Variables don't get changed after going back

Tags: java, android, android-studio-3.0

I have a boolean variable ***public static boolean isInDarkTheme*** but when I try to change the value in my settings activity it only gets changed tempolarily.
I did it so:

```
                if (on) {
                //Do something when Switch button is on/checked
                MainActivity.isInDarkTheme = true;
            } else {
                //Do something when Switch is off/unchecked
                MainActivity.isInDarkTheme = false;
            }
            Log.d("DarkTheme", "SETTINGS " + MainActivity.isInDarkTheme);
```

in my settings the variable is changed but when I go back to my main with the
arrow I created with this:

```
        getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
```

[picture with this button](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yAY5d.png)

it is still the same in the **main**

but! when I use my software key to get back to the MainActivity it get saved
[picture with software back key](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1DJub.png)

Any idea what I can do that it get saved with the other button?

Comment: you might want to learn about the activity life cycle... that will help you. you want to save the change in SharedPref and then get it in the activity you want it in.

Comment: @DroiDev ok I'll try that

Answer (score 0, accepted):

your variable will not be saved and will be collected by garbage collector once the activity is destroyed.

you have to use something like `SharedPreferences`.

to save the variable

```
SharedPreferences sharedPrefrences = getSharedPreferences("pref_name", MODE_PRIVATE);
        sharedPrefrences.edit().putBoolean("isDarkTheme", true).apply();
```

to load

```
SharedPreferences sharedPrefrences = getSharedPreferences("pref_name", MODE_PRIVATE);
                                           //   key   ,   default value
        boolean isDark= sharedPrefrences.getBoolean("isDarkThem", false);
```

read about `SharedPreferences` [here](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/SharedPreferences.html)

Comment: you need to call `apply` or `commit` to save the changes

Comment: `commit()` is synchronous, so you shouldn't call it from the UI thread. `apply()` is recommended.

Answer (score 0):

The most likely reason is that both activities are loaded by different class loaders with the effect that the `MainActivity` you "see" in your `Settings` activity is a different one than the one you "see" in your other activity. You can find that out by logging the classloader "attached" to the `MainActivity` by calling `MainActivity.class.getClassLoader()`